# Reading Host-Bindings of IIS7-Website

Tags: iis-7

is there any possiblity to read all host-bindings of an IIS7-Website and store it to text-file? i would prefer a simple cmd or powershell-call with an `>>` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the applicationHost.config-File under \system32\inetsrv\config you should finding the bindings.

Comment: thanks! but this forces some parsing ... if there won't be any answer with `>>` i will accept this one!